# Complicated query to get results between 2 dates / datetimes

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have this reservation request:
rental car for 2 days starting from 13.02.2016 - 09:00h to 15.02.2016 09:00h

Before confirming availability I want to check my database which cars will be busy / already reserved.

I make this query:

```
select id,modelname from res_reservations 
where resnumber!="9915" and datestart > now() and 
(datestart BETWEEN "2016-02-13 09:00:00" AND "2016-02-15 09:00:00" or
dateend BETWEEN "2016-02-13 09:00:00" AND "2016-02-15 09:00:00") 
order by id ASC
```

in the database res_reservations I have the following records:

```
#id     #modelname      #datestart              #dateend
9912    Volvo           2016-02-25 11:00:00     2016-02-29 09:30:00
9911    Renault         2016-02-12 19:15:00     2016-02-24 12:00:00
9913    Opel            2016-02-16 12:00:00     2016-02-18 12:00:00
```

My query returns no cars are busy for this period but this is not valid because id #9911 will be reserved between 2016-02-12 19:15:00 - 2016-02-24 12:00:00

How to get all cars that are already booked for the period.

Thank you for any help and suggestion.

Just to clarify, I have a serious reason to search the database for reserved cars, but not for the free ones..

Comment: You also need to check for reservations where the startdate is before the new reservation start _and_ the end is after the new reservation end.

Comment: the query uses `resnumber` but in the schematic it appears to use `id` ~ was that just for brevity or is the column called `id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect. You only detect partial overlaps, and don't allow for complete overlaps. e.g. given two dates A+B for a new reservation, and existing X+Y dates in the database, you end up with these possibilities:

```
           x   y
       -------------    
  1    a b |   |           - no overlap
  2    a   b   |          - b = x
  3    a   | b |          - x < b < y
  4    a   |   b          - b = y
  5    a   |   | b        - a < x && b > y
  6        a b |          - full overlap
  7        a   b          - a = x
  8        a   | b        - yada yadayada
  9        |a b| 
  10       | a | b
  11       |   a b
  12       |   | a  b
```

You only check for the conditions where a or b are between the X/Y dates, which doesn't cover all the possibilities, especially #5

Comment: Yes guys, you are all right - this is a logical problem. I had 2 options - leave the task for tomorrow morning or hard brake it at the end of the shift :)) I tried the hard way and this is why I searched help here. I appreciate all of your help guys !

Comment: the logic boils down to `(b >= x) && (a <= y)` for any sort of overlap.

Comment: #Marc B following your advice and testing with the database I discovered it returns correct results ! Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 1):

I think this a logic problem. The query should be the following:

```
select id,modelname 
from res_reservations 
where resnumber!="9915" and datestart > now() and 
   ("2016-02-13 09:00:00" BETWEEN datestart AND dateend or
    "2016-02-15 09:00:00" BETWEEN datestart AND dateend) 
order by id ASC
```

Comment: This will not work on situations  where "2016-02-13 09:00:00" < datestart < dateend < "2016-02-15 09:00:00".

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're capturing bookings that start or end within the booking time, but not bookings that start before and end after it.

The logic you want is to find other bookings where the start is before the end of the period you're looking at, AND the end is after the start of the period. This should get all overlapping bookings.

```
SELECT id,modelname FROM res_reservations 
WHERE resnumber!="9915" AND datestart > NOW() AND 
(datestart < "2016-02-15 09:00:00" AND 
dateend > "2016-02-13 09:00:00" ) 
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: Much cleaner solution.

Comment: #Ilikesleeping - almost working :) but still is missing records to show.. Sorry, but thanks for your help.. the task shall wait for tomorrow morning as I can see..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are after - it is using variables as I was running it from the cmd line but easy to substitute static values or php variables rather than `@var` etc

```
/*
create table if not exists `res_reservations` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `modelname` varchar(50) not null default '0',
  `datestart` datetime not null,
  `dateend` datetime not null,
  primary key (`id`)
) engine=innodb auto_increment=7 default charset=utf8;

insert into `res_reservations` (`id`, `modelname`, `datestart`, `dateend`) values
    (1, 'volvo', '2016-02-25 11:00:00', '2016-02-29 09:30:00'),
    (2, 'renault', '2016-02-12 19:15:00', '2016-02-24 12:00:00'),
    (3, 'opel', '2016-02-01 12:00:00', '2016-02-10 12:00:00'),
    (4, 'ferrari', '2016-02-11 15:45:00', '2016-02-13 07:30:00'),
    (5, 'jaguar', '2016-02-14 18:30:00', '2016-02-24 07:00:00'),
    (6, 'austin7', '2016-02-15 10:00:00', '2016-02-15 14:30:00');
*/


/*
select * from `res_reservations`
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | modelname | datestart           | dateend             |
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Volvo     | 2016-02-25 11:00:00 | 2016-02-29 09:30:00 |
|  2 | Renault   | 2016-02-12 19:15:00 | 2016-02-24 12:00:00 |
|  3 | Opel      | 2016-02-01 12:00:00 | 2016-02-10 12:00:00 |
|  4 | Ferrari   | 2016-02-11 15:45:00 | 2016-02-13 07:30:00 |
|  5 | Jaguar    | 2016-02-14 18:30:00 | 2016-02-24 07:00:00 |
|  6 | Austin7   | 2016-02-15 10:00:00 | 2016-02-15 14:30:00 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
*/


/* assumed to be the dates the customer wants to book a car from/to */
set @ds='2016-02-11 16:00:00';/* new dates */
set @df='2016-02-13 12:00:00';
set @id=9915;

/* show cars that are busy between dates customer wants */
select `id`,`modelname` as 'booked', `datestart` as 'booked-from', `dateend` as 'return-date'
    from `res_reservations`
    where id!=@id and `datestart` > now() and 
       ( 
            not( @ds not between `datestart` and `dateend` and @df not between `datestart` and `dateend` ) 
        ) or ( 
            @ds > `datestart`
        )
    order by `id` asc;

/*
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | booked  | booked-from         | return-date         |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  2 | Renault | 2016-02-12 19:15:00 | 2016-02-24 12:00:00 |
|  5 | Jaguar  | 2016-02-14 18:30:00 | 2016-02-24 07:00:00 |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
*/
```

Having read your last comment ( apologies for delay, had to go to a meeting ) I made a slight amendment which produces:

```
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | booked  | booked-from         | return-date         |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  2 | Renault | 2016-02-12 19:15:00 | 2016-02-24 12:00:00 |
|  3 | Opel    | 2016-02-01 12:00:00 | 2016-02-10 12:00:00 |
|  4 | Ferrari | 2016-02-11 15:45:00 | 2016-02-13 07:30:00 |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I also tried this but it produced the same result:

```
select * from `res_reservations` where `id` not in (
    select `id` from `res_reservations` where 
        id!=@id and `datestart` > now() and not (
            ( @ds between `datestart` and `dateend` ) or ( @df between `datestart` and `dateend` )
        )
    )
```

Comment: #RamRaider, give me a min please to test your code, thanks

Comment: judging by how others have tried and failed I suspect I might too '-)

Comment: #RamRaider have more faith :) looks like it is working or at least it returned me more than 1 records comparing to the other queries. I need to analyze if they are all correct but am already dead meet :) and will continue tomorrow morning. I will let you know ! Thank you ! Thank you all guys !

Comment: #RamRaider your answer / solution works ! i accepted it ! Thank you all guys !

Comment: #RamRaider after I double checked your query also miss result from database. In your case if you search for car between '2016-02-11 16:00:00' and '2016-02-13 12:00:00' you will see that record id#4 from your database will not show up.. Can you confirm with test please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your table has datestart and dateend, which would be populated only when booked (right?), having said that, I think you may have the wrong conditions.

1 - datestart must NOT be between '2016-02-13 09:00:00' and '2016-02-15 09:00:00', so:

```
datestart NOT BETWEEN "2016-02-13 09:00:00" AND "2016-02-15 09:00:00"
```

2 - you want to check if the dateend of a book isn't actually blocking the car from booking, so:

```
AND /* not OR */
dateend NOT BETWEEN "2016-02-13 09:00:00" AND "2016-02-15 09:00:00"
```

Please comment down so we can sort this out.

Comment: William your query returned id#9912 as result on this query but seems to me it is incorrect, right?

Answer (score 0):

Your query will only work when datestart or dateend are inside the interval. It will ignore the situation where (datestart < min_interval) and (dateend > max_interval).

You could add another OR to include the last case:

```
select 
     id,modelname 
from 
    res_reservations 
where 
    resnumber!="9915" and 
    datestart > now() and 
   (datestart BETWEEN "2016-02-13 09:00:00" AND "2016-02-15 09:00:00") or
   (dateend BETWEEN "2016-02-13 09:00:00" AND "2016-02-15 09:00:00") or
   (datestart < "2016-02-13 09:00:00" AND  dateend >"2016-02-15 09:00:00")
order by id ASC
```

Comment: Marcellorvalle your query returned wrong id#4611.. Sorry